# How do I take screenshots of fullscreen games on a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7

I want to take screenshots during gameplay. This is on a PC with Windows 7. I don't want to use Fraps because my PC sucks and can barely run the game.

What are my options? I would prefer something like the OS X screen capture with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

Comment: Using greenshot it is not necessary to have the game window minimized. You can configure it to save the image directly, instead of opening it in an image editor and it wont grab focus.

Comment: Voting to close this one, since there is no built-on solution which is reliable for D3D or OpenGL framebuffer screencaps, beside any commercial solutions, of which there are many, at which point we are off-topic, due to shopping recommendation. (whew, finished without stack overflow error..)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I agree with Oak that Steam is a very viable option for taking screenshots in-game as well as the stock print screen mechanic.

I would like to pose a third option, though. You could always check out a utility like [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org). Which takes the print screen mechanic a step further by automatically saving the the image to the desktop, or other desired location, instead of simply leaving it in clip board ([as seen here](http://getgreenshot.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/settings.jpg)). It's free, safe and open source, and is readily available to download through the homepage I linked above or on Sourceforge. It's a 544 KB download. Unlike an application like CloudApp or Steam's screenshot utility, you will have to upload your image to a host of your choosing.

Comment: ooh.. nice, i will definitely check this out. thanks

Comment: I am sure that will change when it gets updated some more. It's currently at version 0.8. I just wanted to give another option in-case you didn't use Steam. I prefer minimal and open-source software.

Comment: I just installed 0.8 and it's not working while Skyrim is full screen.  It's assigned to `CTRL+PRNT SCRN`.  It works outside of the game, but not when it's full screen.

Comment: I’ve read that Steam only saves screenshots as JPGs. Have they updated it to allow PNGs yet?

Comment: Nice! Does not seem to grab DirectX game screens, though.

Answer (score 42):

Clicking the <kbd>print screen</kbd> button on the top-right of your keyboard (its name is usually abbreviated, e.g. <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd>) will save an image of the current display to the clipboard. You can later paste that image inside a suitable application (e.g. paint). Of course, that means only one screen shot at a time, since hitting the key again will override the clipboard.

Additionally, a **lot** of games have a special treatment for that key, and they will actually generate an image file themselves in some folder (typically under My Documents or AppData).

If you run a game with the Steam overlay on it (whether a real Steam game or just an external game launched through Steam), Steam has a special mechanism for taking screenshots, which saves the images to a special location and allows you to easily upload them online to the Steam cloud. The default key for taking Steam screenshots is  <kbd>F12</kbd>,

Comment: Print Screen will not always work.. For example, Starcraft 2 gave me a black screen. Agree with the other alternatives, though.

Comment: @Bora but SC2 generates a separate image under My Documents when you press that key.

Comment: That is correct. WHat I meant by that is, that the PrintScreen() command, which copies the screenshot into the clipboard, would not work with SC2. Overall, it is not a guaranteed method of taking screenshots in games.

Comment: Print screen does not work for me while Skyrim is full screen.  I am not using Steam.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin What you can do is add Skyrim to Steam as a 'Non-Steam Game'. This allows you to use the Steam Overlay and thus use the `F12` key.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Although considering that Skyrim uses Steamworks, the only way you'd be playing Skyrim without Steam is by using the Black Box version. Which is murky legal territory, I think.

Comment: Games like Starcraft 2 and Skyrim give a black screen because they use the video-adapter’s hardware overlay (not to be confused with Steam’s overlay). This results in a black screen because that’s what is actually there in the software, a black screen. The video-adapter then fills that in with the picture *in hardware*, thus Windows has no access to the rendered output. What’s really odd is that `PrtScr` won’t work with some games like *Safecracker* that *don’t* use the overlay, and instead of a black screen, it gives the *desktop*, clipped to the game’s resolution. Really odd. ಠ_ఠ

Comment: Print Screen DOES NOT capture alternate framebuffers made by exclusive mode apps. Print Screen, on Windows 7, by default, with Aero enabled, captures only DWM's Frame buffer - Your desktop! When Full Screen game is running in true Full Screen, DWM does NOT render to its buffer - it becomes black - so Print Screen leads to a black screen. If the game is full-screen, but not true exclusive full screen, DWM does NOT clear its frame buffer - You usually get your desktop with tiny rectangle because of this. Then what is the solution? Disable Desktop Composition! Print Screen will then WORK :)

Answer (score 12):

Taking screenshots of modern games, especially in fullscreen can indeed be a challenge. Fortunately there’s several ways to get that capture.

## Built-in

### In-game

Many games have a built-in screenshot key, so check the *Controls* section of its options to find out what it is or to set it. The default is usually one of the higher-numbered function keys (e.g. <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>), but as Oak said, some use the obvious choice of <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>.

### Windows

In addition, for many games, Windows own <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> handler will suffice. If it doesn’t work in fullscreen, often, but not always, switching to windowed mode (if the game supports it) will allow it to work.

## Technical Explanation

When <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> doesn’t work for a fullscreen game (or sometimes even a windowed game), it is because the game is using the video-adapter’s hardware overlay <sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_overlay) [[2]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797814.aspx)[[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_overlay)</sup> (not to be confused with software overlays like those of Steam, Fraps, etc.) This is a special buffer ([surface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153344.aspx) for DirectX games) that software can write to which provides hardware acceleration. By nature, it is just a simple (usually near-black) rectangle that the video-adapter fills in with the output image *in hardware*. As a result, Windows does not have access to the rendered image, and so its <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> handler cannot capture it. This is the same for video-players that use hardware acceleration.

## Work-arounds

### Safe

Fortunately, just like you can turn hardware acceleration off for a video-player, you can usually disable a game’s usage of the hardware overlay in the game’s *Video* section of its options by either disabling an option such as “hardware acceleration” or by choosing “software renderer”. Of course this means that the game won't perform as well, so you’ll want to change it back after capturing the image you’re interested in.

### Forced

For games that don’t let you turn off the hardware overlay usage, you can force it off by simply running another program that makes use of hardware acceleration *before* running the game. Since most (all?) video-adapters only support a single overlay surface, running a program that uses it makes it unavailable to other programs. In the past, whenever I wanted to take a screenshot of a video I was watching, I would run Karsten Sperling’s program [*Alpha*](http://spiff.de/alpha.html) (which is a nifty program in its own right) because it would occupy the overlay, so that I can take a screenshot of the video without getting a black rectangle. (I don’t usually do that anymore for videos because I use VLC which a built-in screenshot key that can take correct snaps of the video even when using the overlay because the screenshot function is built-in to the same program that generates the image, so it has access to the actual image.) One caveat is that some games won’t run at all if they can’t use hardware acceleration.

### Hacks

One trick that can be used to allow screen-capture in fullscreen games in Windows Vista and up is to turn off desktop composition for the game (figure 1).

Another trick I have read about is to use a registry hack to enable screenshots for software that uses DirectX:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectDraw]
"EnablePrintScreen"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectDraw]
"EnablePrintScreen"=dword:00000001
```

I haven’t been able to test or confirm this because turning off desktop compositing worked just fine, even for an odd nut like *Safecracker* in which taking a screenshot had previously resulting in a snap of the *desktop* cropped to the dimensions of the game.

### Third Party

And of course there’s third-party programs as others have mentioned on this page. Fraps tends to be popular, and your concern about it impeding performance when your system can barely handle the game as-is is specious. If you turn off the FPS overlays and such, then you *should* be able to use it to take screenshots without it having any additional impact on performance.

Comment: Definitely not correct :) On windows 7 with DWM Running, PrintScreen captures the DWM.EXE's Frame Buffer Object, where the entire desktop is rendered via Direct3D. True Full Screen games render to own primary frame buffer that Print Screen - effectively - don't even see! Just disable Desktop Composition and then PrintScreen will use Kernel's fall-back desktop data stream as source, where all the GDI legacy blitting and framebuffers end up rendered.

Comment: And to add on my own old comment: DWM Cannot be disabled on Windows 8 and up. The only way is to use tools like WindowedBorderlessGaming to force windowed games to fullscreen-like mode compatible with PrintScreen.

Answer (score 3):

[Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) costs some money but is really worth it because once you take a screenshot you can have some image manipulation and add some fun stuff like arrows or notes. It's also great for snagging an entire webpage as an image, or taking just part of your screen. It allows you to grab a screen over 40 different ways.

Comment: wow. looks really nice

Answer (score 1):

You could try Gadwin Printscreen. It's free.