# What is the meaning of symbols in Farming Simulator?

Tags: farming-simulator-2011

What do the symbols in Farming Simulator 2011 mean? I do not know what plant they represent.
I have looked for an answer on the internet but I couldn't find any. These are the crop symbols but im not sure which crop they represent.[image] This is the symbol but there are other ones.(Sorry its a bit blurrred)

Comment: You're going to need to give us more information if you expect us to answer this.  For example, WHICH farming simulator game?  And which symbols?

Comment: A screenshot could help too. [How do I take screenshots of fullscreen games on a Windows 7 PC?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/how-do-i-take-screenshots-of-fullscreen-games-on-a-windows-7-pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should be **Canola**. At least on the first career level in Farm Simulator 2013 (which I believe this is, or an earlier version) you can compare the order of the silos with the order of the prices in the PDA. So from left to right you have Wheat, Barley, Canola and Corn.

Definitely wish there was a better way to see what is what though, as I don't find those icons particularly helpful to a farm newbie like myself :)

[image]