# How do you take screenshots on Assassin's Creed IV?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

So uhm. I've been playing Assassin's Creed IV, and I'm trying to take screenshots... but I haven't been able to. If I press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> the game freezes for a fraction of a second, but if I alt-tab to another program and paste, I see that what's been captured is a screenshot of the computer behind the game. That is, Firefox, Skype, etc. I looked around in Documents, in Images, in the installation folder, even in AppData... Nothing.

So is there a screenshot destination folder that I've missed? Is there some ultra-secret keystroke for taking a screenshot?

If the game itself doesn't allow it, is there a way to make the game windowed? Then I bet Windows' normal screenshot feature wouldn't return what's behind the full-screen game.

Comment: Related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/how-do-i-take-screenshots-of-fullscreen-games-on-a-windows-7-pc Personally, I just go with the Steam option - Add your non-Steam games to Steam and launch them using the Steam shortcut to get the overlay and from there, you use your Steam screenshot shortcut and voilà.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This game for me launches in UPlay through Steam, both of these take screenshots with <kbd>F12</kbd>.

So using this key when in-game will give you  a notification of a screenshot in both Uplay and Steam.

You Steam screenshots will be found in your Steam client in the menu `View > Screenshots`

UPlay saves screenshots into `Users/<Username>/My Pictures/UPlay`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I hope there's a, say, more native way, but that there's some way is good.